# Python accepts keyword arguments in CPython functions?

Tags: python, keyword-argument, python-3.3

I use python3.3 and just found out that it accepts keyword arguments in *some* of its CPython functions:

```
>>> "I like python!".split(maxsplit=1)
['I', 'like python!']
```

But some other functions **don't** accept keyword arguments:

```
>>> sum([1,2,3,4], start = 10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#58>", line 1, in <module>
    sum([1,2,3,4], start = 10)
TypeError: sum() takes no keyword arguments
```

My question is: what is the difference between those functions? Which functions in CPython accept keyword arguments, which functions don't? And of course - why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CPython functions that use [PyArg_ParseTuple()](http://docs.python.org/dev/c-api/arg.html#PyArg_ParseTuple) to parse their arguments do not support keyword arguments (mostly because `PyArg_ParseTuple()` only supports positional parameters, e.g. a simple sequence).

This is explained in the `CPython implementation details` [here](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/expressions.html#calls):

> **CPython implementation detail:** An implementation may provide built-in
>   functions whose positional parameters do not have names, even if they
>   are ‘named’ for the purpose of documentation, and which therefore
>   cannot be supplied by keyword. In CPython, this is the case for
>   functions implemented in C that use `PyArg_ParseTuple()` to parse their
>   arguments.

Comment: Hmm, but in python3.2 you can't insert keyword arguments in `str.split` - so does it mean that they changed the implementation of the function?

Comment: @slallum, I do not have version 3.3 of CPython to confirm it, but it indeed looks like the implementation of `split()` in 3.3 does not use `PyArg_ParseTuple()` anymore.

Comment: @slallum: yes, the implementation changed. [3.3 str.split accepts keywords](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/9371bf2287c4/Objects/unicodeobject.c#l12197) (it uses `PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords()`), but [3.2 doesn't](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.2/Objects/unicodeobject.c#l8691)